# Drupal 8 translate the label of a webform field

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, language-translation

I would like to translate my label from a webform field. I can't do it by the user interface translation, because it didn't show up there.  I added to the content a webform field to link the webform. And then i went to manage display and changed the label of the webform field (with the formatter "Link to form"), to have a custom link to the webform, instead of "Go to webform"

How can I translate it with a hook?

Comment: What did you archive so far ?

Comment: I did a custom module and tried it with a hook_form_alter:

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'entity_view_display_edit_form'){
    $form['fields']['field_schnuppernachmittag']['label']['#title']  =t('new title');
    }
  }

Answer (score 2):

You can translate the whole webform easy with the YAML editor:

[image]

For more documentation I would recommend reading the Internationalization part in this documentation of Drupal

Documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-features

Comment: I will not translate the webform itself. I added to the content a webform field to link the webform. And then i went to manage display and changed the label of the webform field with the formatter "Link to form", to have a custom link to the webform, instead of "Go to webform".